# Refreshing an icon change for chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Google Chrome Extension which changes its icon depending of your IP localization. I face issues with refresh after an extension's icon change.

The icon is actually changing thanks to this command from my `background.js` file.

```
chrome.browserAction.setIcon ( { path: 'france.png' } );
```

Unfortunately, the `setIcon` command seems to be asynchronous. Icon change actually appears a few seconds after the change in the code. Is there a way to force chrome to refresh icons ?

Many chrome extensions seem to be able to control this but I couldn't find out how they manage this.

---

Here are more details :

In order to understand more clearly, I removed all my `javascript` code from different files, except the `setIcon` line. Here is Manifest line which declares my `javascript`files.

```
"background": { "scripts": [ "jquery.min.js", "popup.js", "background.js"] },
```

`popup.js`: Now empty
`background.js`: Only these two following lines :

```
console.log ("I'm background script");
chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: 'france.png'});
```

After extension reload with the extensions manager, I click on its icon. Chrome make the static `html` popup to appear and load `background.js`file. As a proof of it, the text immediately appears on the console window.

But I have to clic a few more times on the icon extension to see it changed by chrome.

I should do something wrong somewhere, but actually, as I removed everything, I have no clue where this delay could come from.

Comment: That does not sound right to me. Especially the "few seconds" part. Are you sure the problem is not elsewhere? Please add more details about your code.

Comment: Please edit your question with new information instead of adding it in comments.

Comment: Done as requested. Thanks

Comment: Still not convinced you're telling us everything. Why would it react to clicking the icon? You have that script included in the popup? Also, what is the resolution of `france.png`?

Comment: Also, I've seen a couple of reports here (with others unable to reproduce) that the popup takes a few seconds to open. Does yours render fast?

Comment: `48x48` and declared in the `manifest.json`. No script included in `popup.html`, and no link to script pages either. I noticed, it's after 4 popup show that the icon is changed. Text from `background.js` appears at first popup disappearance and Icon is changed at 4th one.

Comment: Yes, after the fourth popup disappearance, the new Icon is shown immediately. I actually have no idea how these events would be connected. Thanks for your questions anyway, it helps to figure out what's happening here.

Comment: Try using an icon with the native resolution (19x19) and see if that changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:** Chrome temporarily resets the browserAction icon you've specified when the tab navigates, which is a bug.

**Workaround:** you'll have to update the icon explicitly in every tab using [webNavigation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation) events in the background script:

Your manifest.json should have `webNavigation` permission, of course.

**Warning!** Chrome doesn't cache the icon's imageData and re-calculates it every time setIcon is called, which takes ~10 milliseconds, so let's cache it ourselves. Note that this will also start the event page (or the service worker in ManifestV3), which is very wasteful (at least 50ms), so you may want to [prolong its lifetime artificially](/a/66618269).

```js
const iconPath = 'france.png';
let iconData;

chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted.addListener(updateIcon);
chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener(updateIcon);
chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate.addListener(updateIcon);

(async () => {
  chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
    imageData: iconData = await loadImage(iconPath),
  });
})();

function updateIcon(details) {
  // only update the icon for main page, not iframe/frame
  if (details.frameId != 0) return;
  chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
    imageData: iconData,
    tabId: details.tabId,
  });
}

async function loadImage(url) {
  const img = await createImageBitmap(await (await fetch(url)).blob());
  const {width: w, height: h} = img;
  const canvas = new OffscreenCanvas(w, h);
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h);
  return ctx.getImageData(0, 0, w, h);
}
```

Comment: It's probably worth explaining the performance implications of this, and why this hackery worked.